# Not able to successfully flash Snappy Core image to BBB eMMC.Image too large?

Tags: dd, ubuntu-core, beagleboard, emmc

I have tried several different methods, including the Feb 15 posted [instructions by brechtvc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721495/how-do-i-flash-snappy-ubuntu-core-onto-a-beaglebone-blacks-emmc/734966#734966). Every time, I have a space issue with the eMMC. The latest terminal output, using the brectvc method is:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ unxz -c ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-bbb.img.xz | sudo dd of=/dev/mmcblk1 bs=32M
dd: writing `/dev/mmcblk1': No space left on device
0+467683 records in
0+467682 records out
3867148288 bytes (3.9 GB) copied, 425.36 s, 9.1 MB/s
```

I've tried multiple BBBs, all of them 4GB blacks and one green.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: I am afraid not everyone knows what or who `brechtvc` or `brectvc` is. Could you provide relevant links? Better yet describe in detail what you were doing?

Comment: Sure--I followed this in detail: http://askubuntu.com/questions/721495/how-do-i-flash-snappy-ubuntu-core-onto-a-beaglebone-blacks-emmc/734966#734966

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Ubuntu Core 15.04 images are a fix 4Gb size (most of the size is void though). You can build your own image with the bbb armhf kernel and the correct bbb gadget snap as in https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/ (head over to the "Building your own image" section). `ubuntu-device-flash` has a way to set the size parameter.

This is going to be less a problem starting with Ubuntu Core 16.04 as the default size would be only a few hundreds of Mb, and the first boot is going to resize to available space dynamically. If you want to play with this, a first image is available at http://people.canonical.com/~mvo/all-snaps/bbb-all-snap.img.xz. Be warned though that those ones are under heavy development and not suitable for production (some breaking changes happens daily) :)

Comment: Thanks didrocks--As soon as I got some time I tried to flash the bbb-all-snap.img.xz. I'm very disappointed to report that I got the same no space left error:debian@beaglebone:~$ unxz -c bbb-all-snap.img.xz | sudo dd of=/dev/mmcblk1 bs=32M 
dd: writing `/dev/mmcblk1': No space left on device
0+466534 records in
0+466533 records out
3867148288 bytes (3.9 GB) copied, 389.38 s, 9.9 MB/s
debian@beaglebone:~$

Comment: Since we're not ready for production, and because of what we perceive to be the advantages of Snappy, we're just fine with pre-production. We just want to get it working on the eMMC so we can begin testing.

What I don't understand is why I'm having this issue. I would assume that the various people who have posted guides for flashing Snappy on BBB have succeeded. But don't they have the same space issue? If so, how did they do it when I can't?