# Can't boot Snappy from SD card on Beaglebone Black!

Tags: ssh, arm, ubuntu-core

I've downloaded snappy image to Beaglebone Black: `ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-bbb.img.xz`.

I wrote the image to an SD card, I booted Beaglebone from the SD card, but I can't find the Beaglebone in my network, I get some Leds flashing!

I downloaded another snappy image, the edge version, but also with this image I cant't boot from SD card.
Someone could help me?

I'll wait the FTDI cable that I bougth yesterday and debug to figure out what happens!

Comment: Can you please post the `ssh` command you're running?  You should be using something such as `ubuntu@your.ip`.  Also, please be sure to wait the two minutes, per the [documentation](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/).

Comment: Hi, I figured out that, in fact, "snappy" don't boot, I can boot and SSH ubuntu 14 installed in eMMC, when I put SD card and try to boot from it I can't find BBB in my network!
I will try another image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bougth a FTDI serial cable, I reflashed my SD card with this image: ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-bbb.img.xz, I booted from SD and everything works fine!
After that I could find the ip address and log from SSH!

Answer (score 0):

Which BBB do you have. I have one with 2Gb of eMMC and I cant flash Snappy Ubuntu Core because image has 3,9 Gb. After flashing it is smaller. I think I read somewhere that it's going to be better with next version. But I think that it can be problem with 4Gb eMMC too.

Comment: I think the snappy images are a non flashble images, so doesn't matter wich version of BBB I'm ussing.
I trying to boot from the SD card!

Comment: You have the way to do that...http://askubuntu.com/questions/721495/how-do-i-flash-snappy-ubuntu-core-onto-a-beaglebone-blacks-emmc

Comment: I'm not trying to do that, I trying to boot from SD card!